# JavaScript rendering from HTML to plain text

Tags: javascript, parsing, rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there javascript to convert HTML to markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671930/is-there-javascript-to-convert-html-to-markdown)

I want to submit the server a specific html node from the client, via ajax.

The submission should not have any html tags in it, while the html node does.

For instance, the html node might look like:

```
<div>you have several options:</div>
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>baz</li>
</ul>
```

I want to convert that to something like:

```
you have several options:
* foo
* bar
* baz
```

My context is not a full, generic solution. The html tags I want to support are:
`div`, `p`, `a`, `b`, `i`, `ul`+`li`, `ol`+`li`

Any ideas how to do it without re-inventing the wheel? Is there a JavaScript library that makes such a conversion?

UPDATE: I wasn't aware of the relevant terminology, namely: markdown. Thanks for the link. About to close the question :)

Comment: Sounds like an HTML to markdown converter.

Comment: Or maybe some regex to strip html tags? (keep in mind regex tend to introduce more problems)

Comment: theres a pretty popular javascript html -> markdown converter https://github.com/domchristie/to-markdown