# Is there a way to convert html markup to StackOverflow markup sintax?

Tags: html, markdown, markup, pandoc

Is there a tool like [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) cli for converting [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) markup to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) markup syntax out there? I'm frankly not feeling up to digging the [SO docs](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) over and over to apply simple structure to my SO posts. Stuff like:

```
[link](http://link.com/), 
__italics__, 
**bolds**, 
# etc.
```

are ok, but I don't really want to bother remembering it...

Comment: found this [perl script](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) useful also

Comment: will eventually use pandoc and [html2text python script](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/).

Comment: This would have gotten different results if it did not say things like "not feeling up to digging" and "I don't really want to bother". For example, [Is there javascript to convert HTML to markdown? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671930/is-there-javascript-to-convert-html-to-markdown) got better results. Also, this is a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackOverflow actually uses MarkDown, a popular html syntax. When writing answers and questions, it provides a WYSIWYG editor for common MD functions such as bolding, underlining, headers, links, etc. Comments are usually short and at the most contain some `code` or a [link](http://www.google.com).

If you really need to you can google for a WYSIWYG online editor such as StackEdit that you can write your posts in.

[Heck Yes Markdown](http://heckyesmarkdown.com/) seems to offer a useful api.

Comment: great stuff! and thanks for google link!