# Get text of div with child element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the following example:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
  <h1>The <span class="bold">title</span></h1>
  some text
  <p>and again</p>
  <p>another text.</p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get all the text in one string.
When I just do `$('#mainDiv').text()` it returns the text as `The titlesome textand againanother text`.

In this case I would like to have spaces between the words in child elements.
So I came very close doing:

```
if ($('#mainDiv').find("*").length >= 1) {
  $('#mainDiv').find("*").each(function () {
    sFullText = sFullText + $(this).text().trim().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ') + ' ';
  });
}
```

The result now is: `The titlesome textand again another text`.

So this works when all text is in child elements, but not if some text is in the `mainDiv`.
(the page and it's content is dynamic so I don't know what specific elements are in `mainDiv`)

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem. It seems working: http://jsbin.com/cuqiq/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Me too, http://jsfiddle.net/d4fj32c6/ It is working perfectly :)

Comment: So what you need to know is: how do you get the text from the root element and only the root element?

Answer (score 0):

Using a jQuery plugin from here: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/

```
jQuery.fn.justtext = function() {
    return $(this)  .clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text();
};

// ...

var sFullText = $('#mainDiv').justtext();
if ($('#mainDiv').find("*").length >= 1) {
    $('#mainDiv').find("*").each(function () {
        sFullText = sFullText + ' ' + $(this).text().trim().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try your own code, but using a regex to replace one or multiple whitespace characters `\s` (check [this definition](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp)) with a single space one `' '`. Something like this:

```
$("#mainDiv").text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
```

You can check the example on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4fj32c6/).

Comment: Thanks for you answer so far, but this didn't fix my problem. I saw my example did turn out working with your code, but this sollution does not work for my goal. I have a website and want to scrape it (export of content is not possible). So I made a nodejs script that goes to every link and than get the text of a div and put it in a database.
For example: http://jsfiddle.net/d4fj32c6/11/
as you can see in the fiddle the result starts with "Over het projectDeterra" but it should be "Over het project Deterra" (sorry, text is in Dutch).
hope you can help, thanks!

Comment: @Tober Did it help to solve your problem or there is something else to take into account?

Comment: Ok, I understand your point. Maybe you want to check the [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) library in python. I know is not your target language, but I believe it might get you some ideas. You can also check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671930/is-there-javascript-to-convert-html-to-markdown) about converting HTML to markdown using JS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem exists when you flatten down your html:

```
<div id="mainDiv" style="display:none;"><h1>The <span class="bold">title</span></h1>some text<p>and again</p><p>another text.</p></div>

<div id="result"></div>

$("#result").html($("#mainDiv").text());
```