# Whitelist HTML tag, and best practice in Python

Tags: python, html, security, xss

I'm bulding a Web-App, allowing users to parse and store HTML content from other website.
For the moment, I'm doing this like this :

```
lxml.html.fromstring(html).text_content()
```

So if `html = "Hi ! This is a <a href='#>link</a>"`, the only thing printed if `"Hi ! This is a link"`.

From a security point of view, it's good (no XSS), but functionally, I would like my user to use some HTML tag, with some tag attribute (some = whitelist).

For exemple, I'm ok with `<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>`, but not with `<a href="http://google.com" onClick="alert(1)">Malicious</a>`, which I would want it to be converted to `<a href="http://google.com">Malicious</a>`.

Is there any library in order to do that, or do I have to implement it myself ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to look into Markdown syntax. There could be a markdown parser that could enforce the control you are looking for. You would have to convert the HTML into the Markdown syntax then use the Markdown to recreate the markup in the format you want.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown

A quick search found this markdown parser for python.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown

Converting HTML to markdown could be found in this stackoverflow answer...

[Is there javascript to convert HTML to markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671930/is-there-javascript-to-convert-html-to-markdown)

Comment: Nop, I can't use markdown.
To be more precise, my users send a RSS adress, and I get content from it, and I can't control what's in there.

Comment: Sorry for reviving this question but sounds like you could use XML transformations (XSLT). You could transform your clients RSS html and only accept the elements and attributes you find acceptable.